# Constructing FIRST Set: What rule goes for epsilon

Tags: parsing

I have a question on the algorithm to construct First-Sets for predictive parsing tables.

Let there be a production

```
X => ABCDEFGHabc
```

where upper-case characters are Nonterminal-symbols and lower-case characters are Terminal-symbols correspondingly.

Let's say the Nonterminals from A to G can produce epsilon [ ε ∊ FIRST(A..G) ], then I know you have to add FIRST(H) - {ε} to FIRST(X), but what about FIRST(A..G) - {ε} ?

Aren't the Terminal-symbols that A..G can produce also meant to be taken into consideration? They could possibly appear as input-symbols too, can't they?

So...

Which of the following statements is true and why

To First(X) you...

1 only add the first Nonterminal that does not have epsilon in it's First-Set and that follows a sequence of Nonterminals which do have epsilon in their First-Set

2 add the first Nonterminal that does not have epsilon in it's First-Set and follows a sequence of Nonterminals which have epsilon in their First-Set AND additionally the First-Set of each Nonterminal from that sequence.

... without the epsilon, except when the sequence of Nonterminals that can derive epsilon goes straight through to the rightmost Nonterminal from the right-hand-side of the production and there is no Terminal in-between or after that sequence.

Happy new year

Comment: The FIRST set for a non-terminal contains all the terminals which could possibly be at the beginning of an expansion of that terminal. That's the definition; the algorithm is intended to implement the definition, not to define what the set is. With that in mind, what do you think the answer to your question is?

Comment: Hello rici,

I formulated the two possible answers and took a guess that answer 2 might be correct because "nullable non-terminals" might still potentially appear in the input-stream. What more could I do than present my conjecture and ask if the answer is correct, or if I am wrong? And if I'm wrong, it would be insightful to have an explanation why my reasoning was not correct.

Best wishes

Comment: You could try your solutions out on a simple grammar and see if they produce the correct result; that should certainly be sufficient to discard the first one. I find your wording a bit hard to follow but I think it is correct; I provided another formulation as an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The simple explanation is that the first set of a sequence `α` of grammar symbols is the set of terminals which could start the expansion of `α`. And the FIRST set of a non-terminal is the union of the FIRST sets of the right-hand sides of the productions of that non-terminal.

We can compute the FIRST set of a sequence `α` recursively:

- If `α` is `ε`, then FIRST(`α`) is `{ε}`
- If `α` is `aβ`, then FIRST(`α`) is `{a}`.
- If `α` is `Aβ` and `ε` ∉ FIRST(`A`), then FIRST(`α`) is FIRST(`A`)
- If `α` is `Aβ` and `ε` ∈ FIRST(`A`), then FIRST(`α`) is FIRST(`A`) ∪ FIRST(`β`)

It should be easy to see the result of repeatedly applying the last rule.

In case it wasn't obvious, I'm using lower case letters for terminals, upper case letters for non-terminals, and greek letters for sequences (possibly empty) of grammar symbols (terminals or non-terminals), with `ε` reserved, as usual, for the empty sequence.

Comment: Hello rici,

thanks for your answer!

I guess your rule-4 is what i meant by my statement-2. 

The _point_ is that the proper algorithm for FIRST set generation also encompasses the "terminals which could possibly be at the beginning of an expansion" _of each "nullable non-terminal" too_ which could appear in `α`. It doesn't only encompass those with `ε` ∉ FIRST(`<nonterminal>`).

I hope my wording is more understandable by applying some of your wording in quotes. Too bad the markdown doesn't let you underline things...

Comment: The reason i am asking is rule-2 in the dragon book p. 221: It states for the production `X => Y_1 Y_2 Y_k` ... `If Y_i does not derive ε then we add
nothing more to FIRST(X) , but if Y_1 =>* E, then we add FIRST(Y_2 ) , and
so on.`
In the case that `Y_1 =>* ε` however it doesn't add FIRST(Y_1) and just skips it.

Comment: @vonspotz: The sentence just before that says "everything in FIRST(Y1) is surely in FIRST(X)". How could you possibly interpret that as meaning that it intends to skip FIRST(Y1)?

Comment: What they are saying, which is the same thing as I'm saying, is that you add the FIRST set for some symbol in the righthand size if every symbol to its left is nullable. Whether or not the symbol itself is nullable is irrelevant.